# Invert axis in yt plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, yt

I want to put two plots in a paper but I am stuck with them standing "tall".

```py
grid = AxesGrid(
   fig,
   (0.075, 0.075, 0.85, 0.85),
   nrows_ncols=(2, 1),
   axes_pad=0.1,
   label_mode="L",
   share_all=True,
   cbar_location="right",
   cbar_mode="single",
   cbar_size="3%",
   cbar_pad="2%",
   )


for i, fn in enumerate(fns):

   ds = yt.load(fn)  # load data
   p = yt.SlicePlot(ds, "z", ("gas", "density"))
   plot = p.plots[("gas", "density")]
   plot.figure = fig
   plot.axes = grid[i].axes
   plot.cax = grid.cbar_axes[i]

   p.render()
plt.show()
```

If I use this code this is what I get.

[image]

I tried to use gridspec but I never succeded

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. all the code necessary to create the plot, which includes the imports and a simple dataset (preferably something randomly generated or small).